Legality of custom Range units
In regards to the Range and Content-Range headers, RFC7233 mentions that:

     range-unit       = bytes-unit / other-range-unit

[...]

   Range units are intended to be extensible.  New range units ought to
   be registered with IANA, as defined in Section 5.1.

     other-range-unit = token

Note that ought to is not a capitalized keyword like MUST/CAN.
Does this mean that using unregistered custom Range units makes an implementation non standards compliant?
For example, could a compliant reverse proxy reject such requests?
